# Uglify-js throw error and parse error happens

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

I am very sorry that i m asking about the `uglify-js` error. However I tried every method that proposed by members in this sites but still got nothing improvement. I m trying to gulp the google polymer app to dist folder. Somehow there always have error throws and it made me unable to prepare and compile the app to android through apache cordova successfully. Very hope the members here really need to check this coding since i spent two week on this but got nothing.

my `gulpfile.js`:

```
'use strict';

// Include Gulp & Tools We'll Use
var gulp = require('gulp');

var jshint = require('gulp-jshint');
var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')();
var del = require('del');
var runSequence = require('run-sequence');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var reload = browserSync.reload;
var merge = require('merge-stream');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
var glob = require('glob');

var build = require('gulp-build');

var AUTOPREFIXER_BROWSERS = [
  'ie >= 10',
  'ie_mob >= 10',
  'ff >= 30',
  'chrome >= 34',
  'safari >= 7',
  'opera >= 23',
  'ios >= 7',
  'android >= 4.4',
  'bb >= 10'
];

var styleTask = function (stylesPath, srcs) {
  return gulp.src(srcs.map(function(src) {
      return path.join('app', stylesPath, src);
    }))
    .pipe($.changed(stylesPath, {extension: '.css'}))
    .pipe($.autoprefixer(AUTOPREFIXER_BROWSERS))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('.tmp/' + stylesPath))
    .pipe($.if('*.css', $.cssmin()))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/' + stylesPath))
    .pipe($.size({title: stylesPath}));
};

// Compile and Automatically Prefix Stylesheets
gulp.task('styles', function () {
  return styleTask('styles', ['**/*.css']);
});

gulp.task('elements', function () {
  return styleTask('elements', ['**/*.css']);
});

// Lint JavaScript
gulp.task('jshint', function () {
  return gulp.src([
      'app/scripts/**/*.js',
      'app/elements/**/*.js',
      'app/elements/**/*.html'
    ])
    .pipe(reload({stream: true, once: true}))
    .pipe($.jshint.extract()) // Extract JS from .html files
    .pipe($.jshint())
    .pipe($.jshint.reporter('jshint-stylish'))
    .pipe($.if(!browserSync.active, $.jshint.reporter('fail')));
});

// Optimize Images
gulp.task('images', function () {
  return gulp.src('app/images/**/*')
    .pipe($.cache($.imagemin({
      progressive: true,
      interlaced: true
    })))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/images'))
    .pipe($.size({title: 'images'}));
});

// Copy All Files At The Root Level (app)
gulp.task('copy', function () {
  var app = gulp.src([
    'app/*',
    '!app/test',
    '!app/precache.json'
  ], {
    dot: true
  }).pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));

  var bower = gulp.src([
    'bower_components/**/*'
  ]).pipe(gulp.dest('dist/bower_components'));

  var elements = gulp.src(['app/elements/**/*.html'])
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/elements'));

  var swBootstrap = gulp.src(['bower_components/platinum-sw/bootstrap/*.js'])
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/elements/bootstrap'));

  var swToolbox = gulp.src(['bower_components/sw-toolbox/*.js'])
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/sw-toolbox'));

  var vulcanized = gulp.src(['app/elements/elements.html'])
    .pipe($.rename('elements.vulcanized.html'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/elements'));

  return merge(app, bower, elements, vulcanized, swBootstrap, swToolbox)
    .pipe($.size({title: 'copy'}));
});

// Copy Web Fonts To Dist
gulp.task('fonts', function () {
  return gulp.src(['app/fonts/**'])
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/fonts'))
    .pipe($.size({title: 'fonts'}));
});

// Scan Your HTML For Assets & Optimize Them
gulp.task('html', function () {
  var assets = $.useref.assets({searchPath: ['.tmp', 'app', 'dist']});

  return gulp.src(['app/**/*.html', '!app/{elements,test}/**/*.html'])
    // Replace path for vulcanized assets
    .pipe($.if('*.html', $.replace('elements/elements.html', 'elements/elements.vulcanized.html')))
    .pipe(assets)
    // Concatenate And Minify JavaScript
    .pipe($.if('*.js', $.uglify({preserveComments: 'some'})))
    // Concatenate And Minify Styles
    // In case you are still using useref build blocks
    .pipe($.if('*.css', $.cssmin()))
    .pipe(assets.restore())
    .pipe($.useref())
    // Minify Any HTML
    .pipe($.if('*.html', $.minifyHtml({
      quotes: true,
      empty: true,
      spare: true
    })))
    // Output Files
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
    .pipe($.size({title: 'html'}));
});

// Vulcanize imports
gulp.task('vulcanize', function () {
  var DEST_DIR = 'dist/elements';

  return gulp.src('dist/elements/elements.vulcanized.html')
    .pipe($.vulcanize({
      dest: DEST_DIR,
      strip: true,
      inlineCss: true,
      inlineScripts: true
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(DEST_DIR))
    .pipe($.size({title: 'vulcanize'}));
});

// Generate a list of files that should be precached when serving from 'dist'.
// The list will be consumed by the <platinum-sw-cache> element.
gulp.task('precache', function (callback) {
  var dir = 'dist';

  glob('{elements,scripts,styles}/**/*.*', {cwd: dir}, function(error, files) {
    if (error) {
      callback(error);
    } else {
      files.push('index.html', './', 'bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js');
      var filePath = path.join(dir, 'precache.json');
      fs.writeFile(filePath, JSON.stringify(files), callback);
    }
  });
});

// Clean Output Directory
gulp.task('clean', del.bind(null, ['.tmp', 'dist']));

// Watch Files For Changes & Reload
gulp.task('serve', ['styles', 'elements', 'images'], function () {
  browserSync({
    notify: false,
    snippetOptions: {
      rule: {
        match: '<span id="browser-sync-binding"></span>',
        fn: function (snippet) {
          return snippet;
        }
      }
    },
    // Run as an https by uncommenting 'https: true'
    // Note: this uses an unsigned certificate which on first access
    //       will present a certificate warning in the browser.
    // https: true,
    server: {
      baseDir: ['.tmp', 'app'],
      routes: {
        '/bower_components': 'bower_components'
      }
    }
  });

  gulp.watch(['app/**/*.html'], reload);
  gulp.watch(['app/styles/**/*.css'], ['styles', reload]);
  gulp.watch(['app/elements/**/*.css'], ['elements', reload]);
  gulp.watch(['app/{scripts,elements}/**/*.js'], ['jshint']);
  gulp.watch(['app/images/**/*'], reload);
});

// Build and serve the output from the dist build
gulp.task('serve:dist', ['default'], function () {
  browserSync({
    notify: false,
    snippetOptions: {
      rule: {
        match: '<span id="browser-sync-binding"></span>',
        fn: function (snippet) {
          return snippet;
        }
      }
    },
    // Run as an https by uncommenting 'https: true'
    // Note: this uses an unsigned certificate which on first access
    //       will present a certificate warning in the browser.
    // https: true,
    server: 'dist'
  });
});

// Build Production Files, the Default Task
gulp.task('default', ['clean'], function (cb) {
  runSequence(
    ['copy', 'styles'],
    'elements',
    ['jshint', 'images', 'fonts', 'html'],
    'vulcanize', 'precache',
    cb);
});


gulp.task('build', function() {
  gulp.src('scripts/*.js')
      .pipe(build({ GA_ID: '123456' }))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
});

gulp.task('lint', function() {
  return gulp.src('./lib/*.js')
    .pipe(jshint())
    .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'));
});

gulp.task('uglify', function() {
  gulp.src('public/js/*.js')
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'))
});

gulp.task('scripts', ['clean'], function () {
      return gulp.src('js/*.js')
        .pipe(uglify().on('error', function(e){
            console.log(e);
         }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('minjs'));
  });

gulp.task('js', function(){
    return gulp.src(paths.src.js)
        .pipe(babel())
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist.js));
});

gulp.task("uglify-src", function() {
    gulp.src([ "src/js/**/*.js" ])
    .pipe(concat("app.js"))
    .pipe(ignore.exclude([ "**/*.map" ]))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("dist/js"));
});
// Load tasks for web-component-tester
// Adds tasks for `gulp test:local` and `gulp test:remote`
try { require('web-component-tester').gulp.init(gulp); } catch (err) {}

// Load custom tasks from the `tasks` directory
try { require('require-dir')('tasks'); } catch (err) {}
```

my gulp result

```
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
 Error at new JS_Parse_Error (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Users\CharlesCks\polymer-1.0.2\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:22:1),`<anonymous>:1526:18)
        at js_error (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Users\Charles Cks\polymer-1.0.2\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:1534:11)
        at parse_error (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Users\Charles Cks\polymer-1.0.2\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:1647:9)
        at next_token (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Users\Charles Cks\polymer-1.0.2\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:1911:9)
        at skip_line_comment (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Users\Charles Cks\polymer-1.0.2\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:1753:16)
        at handle_slash (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Users\Charles Cks\polymer-1.0.2\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:1842:20)
        at Object.next_token [as input] (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Users\Charles Cks\polymer-1.0.2\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:1898:27)
        at next (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Users\Charles Cks\polymer-1.0.2\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2011:25)
        at semicolon (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Users\Charles Cks\polymer-1.0.2\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2058:30)
        at simple_statement (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Users\Charles Cks\polymer-1.0.2\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2239:73)
        at eval (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Users\Charles Cks\polymer-1.0.2\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2107:20)
        at eval (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Users\Charles Cks\polymer-1.0.2\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2072:24)
        at eval (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Users\Charles Cks\polymer-1.0.2\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2819:23)
        at Object.parse (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Users\Charles Cks\polymer-1.0.2\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2829:7)
        at C:\Users\Charles Cks\polymer-1.0.2\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:61:33
        at Array.forEach (native)
```

the events.js

```
exports._ElementCache = function () {

    var cache = {},
        guidCounter = 1,
        expando = "data" + (new Date).getTime();

    this.getData = function (elem) {
        var guid = elem[expando];
        if (!guid) {
            guid = elem[expando] = guidCounter++;
            cache[guid] = {};
        }
        return cache[guid];
    };

    this.removeData = function (elem) {
        var guid = elem[expando];
        if (!guid) return;
        delete cache[guid];
        try {
            delete elem[expando];
        }
        catch (e) {
            if (elem.removeAttribute) {
                elem.removeAttribute(expando);
            }
        }
    };
};

/**
 * Fix an event
 * @param event
 * @returns {*}
 */
exports._fixEvent = function (event) {

    function returnTrue() {
        return true;
    }

    function returnFalse() {
        return false;
    }

    if (!event || !event.stopPropagation) {
        var old = event || window.event;

        // Clone the old object so that we can modify the values
        event = {};

        for (var prop in old) {
            event[prop] = old[prop];
        }

        // The event occurred on this element
        if (!event.target) {
            event.target = event.srcElement || document;
        }

        // Handle which other element the event is related to
        event.relatedTarget = event.fromElement === event.target ?
            event.toElement :
            event.fromElement;

        // Stop the default browser action
        event.preventDefault = function () {
            event.returnValue = false;
            event.isDefaultPrevented = returnTrue;
        };

        event.isDefaultPrevented = returnFalse;

        // Stop the event from bubbling
        event.stopPropagation = function () {
            event.cancelBubble = true;
            event.isPropagationStopped = returnTrue;
        };

        event.isPropagationStopped = returnFalse;

        // Stop the event from bubbling and executing other handlers
        event.stopImmediatePropagation = function () {
            this.isImmediatePropagationStopped = returnTrue;
            this.stopPropagation();
        };

        event.isImmediatePropagationStopped = returnFalse;

        // Handle mouse position
        if (event.clientX != null) {
            var doc = document.documentElement, body = document.body;

            event.pageX = event.clientX +
            (doc && doc.scrollLeft || body && body.scrollLeft || 0) -
            (doc && doc.clientLeft || body && body.clientLeft || 0);
            event.pageY = event.clientY +
            (doc && doc.scrollTop || body && body.scrollTop || 0) -
            (doc && doc.clientTop || body && body.clientTop || 0);
        }

        // Handle key presses
        event.which = event.charCode || event.keyCode;

        // Fix button for mouse clicks:
        // 0 == left; 1 == middle; 2 == right
        if (event.button != null) {
            event.button = (event.button & 1 ? 0 :
                (event.button & 4 ? 1 :
                    (event.button & 2 ? 2 : 0)));
        }
    }

    return event;
};

/**
 * @constructor
 */
exports._EventManager = function (cache) {

    var nextGuid = 1;

    this.addEvent = function (elem, type, fn) {

        var data = cache.getData(elem);

        if (!data.handlers) data.handlers = {};

        if (!data.handlers[type])
            data.handlers[type] = [];

        if (!fn.guid) fn.guid = nextGuid++;

        data.handlers[type].push(fn);

        if (!data.dispatcher) {
            data.disabled = false;
            data.dispatcher = function (event) {

         if (data.disabled) return;    // ***  events.js:141  ***

                event = exports._fixEvent(event);

                var handlers = data.handlers[event.type];
                if (handlers) {
                    for (var n = 0; n < handlers.length; n++) {
                        handlers[n].call(elem, event);
                    }
                }
            };
        }

        if (data.handlers[type].length == 1) {
            if (document.addEventListener) {
                elem.addEventListener(type, data.dispatcher, false);
            }
            else if (document.attachEvent) {
                elem.attachEvent("on" + type, data.dispatcher);
            }
        }

    };

    function tidyUp(elem, type) {

        function isEmpty(object) {
            for (var prop in object) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        var data = cache.getData(elem);

        if (data.handlers[type].length === 0) {

            delete data.handlers[type];

            if (document.removeEventListener) {
                elem.removeEventListener(type, data.dispatcher, false);
            }
            else if (document.detachEvent) {
                elem.detachEvent("on" + type, data.dispatcher);
            }
        }

        if (isEmpty(data.handlers)) {
            delete data.handlers;
            delete data.dispatcher;
        }

        if (isEmpty(data)) {
            cache.removeData(elem);
        }
    }

    this.removeEvent = function (elem, type, fn) {

        var data = cache.getData(elem);

        if (!data.handlers) return;

        var removeType = function (t) {
            data.handlers[t] = [];
            tidyUp(elem, t);
        };

        if (!type) {
            for (var t in data.handlers) removeType(t);
            return;
        }

        var handlers = data.handlers[type];
        if (!handlers) return;

        if (!fn) {
            removeType(type);
            return;
        }

        if (fn.guid) {
            for (var n = 0; n < handlers.length; n++) {
                if (handlers[n].guid === fn.guid) {
                    handlers.splice(n--, 1);
                }
            }
        }
        tidyUp(elem, type);

    };

    this.proxy = function (context, fn) {
        if (!fn.guid) {
            fn.guid = nextGuid++;
        }
        var ret = function () {
            return fn.apply(context, arguments);
        };
        ret.guid = fn.guid;
        return ret;
    };
};



/**
 * Trigger a click on an element
 * @param elem
 */
exports.triggerClick = function (elem) {

    var evObj;

    if (document.createEvent) {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            evObj = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
            evObj.initEvent("click", true, true);
            elem.dispatchEvent(evObj);
        }, 0);
    } else {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            if (document.createEventObject) {
                evObj = document.createEventObject();
                evObj.cancelBubble = true;
                elem.fireEvent("on" + "click", evObj);
            }
        }, 0);
    }
};

var cache = new exports._ElementCache();
var eventManager = new exports._EventManager(cache);

eventManager.triggerClick = exports.triggerClick;

exports.manager = eventManager;
```

Comment: What does the code look like around this line: `events.js:141`?

Comment: J. Titus, i posted the events.js, you may see when scrolling i put a statement   ***  events.js:141  ***.

Comment: unfortunally i made changes to the coding. It is still not worked.

Comment: Worked for me.

```.pipe($.uglify().on('error', function(err){
            console.log(err);
         }))
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is coming late but i just had a similar issue with the gulp-uglify throwing an error. uglify in the gulpfile.js is used to minify js files. I will suggest you check all your js files as there is likely to be an error in one of them. Ill advice you start with the app.js